# Access field in graphQL array query dynamically

Tags: arrays, react-native, graphql

I have the following return code

```
return (
  <FlatList
    data={data.groupQuery.entities}
    keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
    renderItem={
      ({ item }) => {
        return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            />
            <Text style={styles.label}>Name: {item.fieldName}</Text> // I want to display fieldName value here
          </View>
        )
      }
    }
  />
);
```

Given the above, how can I access the `fieldName` values from the query array in the photo. I want to call the field dynamically.

---

**Updated query:**

Apologies for some confusion to this thread. Now my goal is to access the `fieldName` value from the photo below. I tried `{item.fieldTradingPlatform.entity.fieldName}` but getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'fieldName' of undefined`

[image]

---

**Previous query:**

[image]

With static call, I can output the value of first array:

```
console.log(data.groupQuery.entities[0].fieldName)
```

Comment: Is the above code not working? What behavior are you seeing? What behavior did you expect? Are you seeing any errors in the console?

Comment: I actually have 2 different queries... 1> without the integer array, and `{item.fieldName}` outputs the `fieldName`. 2> This updated version of my query. So I want to know how to dynamically call the values.

Comment: My concern is im not sure how to restructure the code so I can get both the [0] and [1] values from that query. Should we define an index value? Then how I can add this?

Comment: The `FlatList` component already dynamically creates a view for each item in the array of items you pass to the `data` prop. The value of each item is available inside the `renderItem` function. You're already dynamically rendering some views based on the passed-in array. If you have two items in your array, a separate view should be rendered for each of those items.

Comment: Again, it's not clear from your question and your comments what **behavior** you're expecting and what you're actually seeing when you run your code. What about your current code is not working as expected?

Comment: what im doing here is doing a query and pass it to other component and display it in the mobile app. Basically, again im trying to access a nested array from the query. Okay, so base on the above, I was able to display the `fieldName` just using the `{item.fieldName}`. Not sure why I dont test it earlier. But I have more nested array value I need to access. I will update the above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Graph Query Data

Try like this to access field name

```
renderItem={({ item }) => (
                    <View>
                        {
                            item.fieldTradingPlatform.map((a, i) => {
                                return <Text>{a.entity.fieldName}</Text>
                            })
                        }
                    </View>)}
```

fieldTradingPlatform is a array not a single object.

Comment: You are genius. Thank you so much!

Comment: BTW, I get this warning in the app and console UI `Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop. Check the render method of CellRenderer. See https://fb.**/react-warning-keys for more information. in View (at PlatformComponent.js:74)` in line `<View...` of `item.fieldTradingPlatform.map((a, i) => {
                  return (
                    <View style={styles.container}>`